# Unable to see posts after migration from bluehost to Digitialocean

Tags: wordpress, migration, digital-ocean

I was migrating my website from bluehost to Digitalocean.

Following are the steps I took:

1. Downloaded zip of **wp-content** from bluehost
2. Exported database dump from bluehost
3. Replace **wp-content** folder in my wordpress folder on Digitalocean with the folder I got from Step 1
4. Imported database dump to Digitalocean. I can query and see, the data is in the table

I am able to see all old plugins from bluehost, but I am unable to see my old posts or pages from bluehost. All these data are available in the database. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Did you try to re-update your post url ?

Comment: re-update. how?

Comment: Check here : http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-update-urls-when-moving-your-wordpress-site/

Comment: didn't worked out.. i am getting 0 results and the message `This happens if a URL is incorrect OR if it is not found in the content. Check your URLs and try again.`

Answer (score -1):

did you replace the domain settings in the wp_options table? maybe share the URL also please.

Comment: the good news is that through the API rest your posts are visible, for example I see one titled "Sort collection by object attribute.".
So you may have a permalink issue. Just login to your admin and re save the permalinks settings.

Comment: I re-saved it.. didn't work out.. P.S: I don't have such title

Comment: do you see your posts in the admin?
check this json: crexdata.com/wp-json/wp/v2/
is that your data?
if not, something went wrong while importing the db. Maybe you imported the wrong dump.

Comment: i was using a plugin to update the permalink.. can it be causing problem?

Comment: I usually use this plugin for migrations: https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ is very good! Maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: i already closed the previous account.. i thought this would be good enough

Comment: you don't need a plugin to update the permalink, just go to crexdata.com/wp-admin/options-permalink.php and re save the settings

Comment: oh that plugin from WP Beginner is to update the domain, those I said in my first answer